# variable call from one package to another

Tags: android, package

A very basic problem:
I have two packages in same project. package1 and Package2 in Package1 I am having some variable arrays: array1, array2. That array I have to call into package2's java class file.
In package2's class file I am already having it extends Fragment so I can't extend another class file.. So how to call.

any clue is helpful..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple thing first check that those variable should not be private and if those array is not private than you can import your first package in your current class and use those variable with the package name like-

1)first class

```
package com.zxo;
public class ActionItem {

    public static String abc[]={"a","b","c"};

}
```

2)where you want to use that just do these thing-

```
import com.zxo;
package com.anyname;

String value_of_array=com.zhousho.remote.ActionItem.abc[0];
```

similarly you can access any value or variable of that package here